# Looking for Active Model Serializer like nested, associative output for Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, active-model-serializers

Please forgive me if my research was inadequate. I've been reading the docs and searching this site to no avail for over an hour and I could really use some expert help.

With Rails, I can use Active Model Serializer to send data associated with the set queried. For example, let us say that I have Users, and Users have many Posts. Let us say that I want output that looks like this:

```
[
- {
id: 1,
username: "Matz",
posts: [
   - {
   id: 35,
   title: "Hello world",
   content_body: "This is the content of my post."
},
-{
   id: 98,
   title: "Foo Bar",
   content_body: "This is the content of my other post."
}]},
]
```

Using Active Model Serializer this would be trivial. What I'm hoping is to get similar output using Sequelize.

My associations are working fine, and I am able to do for instance this:

```
return db.Users.findByPk(user_id)
    .then(user => user.getPosts())
    .then(posts => res.send(posts))
```

*** edited to add ***
One problem is that what I would really like to do is put the include inside of the user.getPosts(), for example.

What I need is the get the Posts belonging to a User, then get the Tag to which those Posts belong.

---

Thanks so much for any help. I am trying to avoid too many fetch requests.

Comment: You can use include in the query: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/querying.html#relations---associations

Comment: Thanks. I must just be doing something wrong because this is not working for me.

Comment: One issue is that I would need to .findByPk for the User, then do something like user.getPosts() and do the include within the getPosts(). Which doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include within .getPosts does work. I had not understood the docs entirely.

Because I imported the models as so in my app.js:

```
const db = require('./models');
```

I needed to write the following:

```
return db.Users.findByPk(user_id)
    .then(user => user.getPosts({
      include: [{
        model: db.Tags
     }]
}))
    .then(posts => res.send(posts))
```